# POST call in Safari using angularjs $http is not being called

Tags: angularjs, ajax, http, asynchronous, safari

I have an angular application. I am having in issue with a POST call and using the $http directive. In my controller I make two calls through the consumption of Api service that I made: getMe() and and assignments(csv):

```js
assignments: function(csv) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/numbers/assignments',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      data: $.param({
        skipBillables: false,
        assignments: csv,
      })
    }).success(function(data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function(data) {
      deferred.reject(data);
    })
    return deferred.promise;
  },
  getMe: function() {
    return this.cachedGet("/users/me");
  },
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the actual calls in the controller. We make the GET request to the users end point, and then post to assignments in the callback.

```js
Api.getMe().then(function(data) {



}, function(error) {
  $window.location.reload();
}).finally(function() {
  var checkouttollfreenumber = '1' + $scope.savedTollFreeNumberCheckout.tfn;
  var assignObj = [{
    phoneNum: checkouttollfreenumber,
    email: owner.emailAddress,
    percent: 0,
  }];
  var csvFile = downloadCSV(assignObj);
  console.log(csvFile);
  Api.assignments(csvFile).then(function(data) {
    //do something
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
```

It executes properly in Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari. In Safari, it calls a GET request to http:applicationname.com/18885052939,useremail@email.com,percentageparameter. The request is actually calling the serialized parameters of the POST call to assignments.

In Chrome, we have the correct behavior. After the GET request on users/me, we hit http://local.appname.com:9000/api/numbers/assignments with the POST data parameters.

Not sure what is causing the error in Safari, but wondering where I am going wrong. This is an older version of angular (1.2.15).

Comment: The latest bug fix for Angular v1.2 is v1.2.32. Try that version to see if any Safari related bugs have been fixed.

Comment: thanks @georgeawg I'll give it a try.

Comment: @georgeawg tried it. It doesn't seem to be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With AngularJS v1.4, the framework makes the url parameter serializer available as [$httpParamSerializer](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer) to use with POST requests to APIs that only support content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
function assignments(csv){
    promise = $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/numbers/assignments',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      data: {
        skipBillables: false,
        assignments: csv,
      },
      transformRequest: $httpParamSerializer
    });
    return promise;
}
```

For APIs that don't accept the AngularJS framework default of `application/json`, application programmers no longer need to write their own serializer or load jQuery for its serializer.